# How to run a custom EXE file from Application page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, application-pages

I'm using SharePoint 2007. I need to call a custom EXE file in the "C:\Program Files..." location through a SharePoint application page. Need to pass command line parameters as well. The exe does a file type conversion based on the parameters. The parameters carry the original file location in the hard drive. Can i invoke the exe through C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call the exe from server side code then you can use the below code, All you need to do is to include the namespace, `using System.Diagnostics;,` and at the place where you wish to start the application, call the `Process.Start` method

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( @"C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe" );
```

OR

```
// For the example
const string ex1 = "C:\\";
const string ex2 = "C:\\Dir";
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "dcm2jpg.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
//or something like below 
startInfo.Arguments = "-f j -o \"" + ex1 + "\" -z 1.0 -s y " + ex2;
Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo)
```

[Process.StartInfo Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.startinfo.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have one more question on this. How to send multiple arguments. For example if the ese excepts multiple arguments like: ABC.exe "C:\SomeFolder\sourceFileName.pdf" -o "C:\AnotherFolder\Resultingfile.swf" I tried `proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Concat(@"C:\pdf\", file.Name, @"-o C:\swf\", swfFile);`. didnt work out

Comment: @Shaamil, check my answer, I have edited it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can certainly invoke a .exe file using C#.  You would use the Process.Start command from the System.Diagnostics namespace.  Remember all servers that run this code will need a copy of the exe in the location you specify to run it from.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

No, but if its an activeX component you can call it through javascript, if you are sure that all the users are running IE.

If you should call the exe, it should be on the server and then with a lot of hacks you could access the client computer if its on a network where you can control the security.. Not a very clean solution that I would recommend..